# Simplest clip-path experiment not working when linking to svg

Tags: svg, clip-path

I'm trying to master the art of clipping images with SVG paths, but quickly  became overwhelmed trying to make it happen correctly in a live site, so I'm trying to get a simple, bare-bones test working locally on my desktop.

I'm using Safari. The current issue is: when I try to link to a separate SVG file, it does not work, but if I refer to an svg within the document, it does. Why would this be? Ultimately I need the SVG to be a separate file.

My html:

`

```
    <style type="text/css">
    img#image-24 {
        clip-path: url(#myClip);
    }
    </style>
            
</head>

<body>
    
    <center>
    <img id="image-24" src="home-adults.jpg" width="600" height="310">
    </center>
    
    <svg width="0" height="0">
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="myClip">
          <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="40"/>
          <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="40"/>
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
    </svg>

</body>
```

`

but if I copy the SVG code into a separate file in the same directory, called test.svg, with just the svg code as seen above...

```
<svg width="0" height="0">
<defs>
<clipPath id="myClip">
<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="40"/>
<circle cx="60" cy="60" r="40"/>
</clipPath>
</defs>
</svg>
```

and try to reference it, i.e.:

`clip-path: url(test.svg#myClip);`

It does NOT work.

(Browser prefix doesn't seem to make any difference, in either case.)

After much reading about the various parameters of SVG files and the clipPath function, I'm trying to get down to basics here with the simplest example I can...  hope someone can help me get off of square one!

Comment: Have you tried Firefox?

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109212

Comment: Hmm, the linked-file syntax doesn't work for me in FF or Chrome either. Though strangely, the hashtag-only version does work in FF - with only the webkit prefix, not "-moz-". Weird. I guess this is not currently a viable option for clipping images. Too bad!

Comment: Firefox works unprefixed and has regression tests to prove it. Note that if you reference an external file it must be a valid SVG file in XML format with namespaces. You've not really shown what your external file looks like.

Comment: @RobertLongson I've edited my question to specify the contents of the SVG file. I see I'm missing a namespace declaration. Am researching that aspect now...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course